Snapd is slow and broken on 24.04

After investigating further with journalctl -xeu snapd.failure.service I filed a bug report with the findings: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/2081579


I have a desktop system with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installed. I used the TPM FDE installation option based on the snapped kernel image.
I noticed that the go command was not responding and rebooted, hoping that the issue would be solved, but it was not. Ubuntu 24.04 directs users to install golang as a classic snap to use a recent version. So I wanted to check if there is something wrong with snapd. Turns out, yes there is an issue again with snapd. See "Observation and summary" below.
Question: How do we fix this situation without breaking the system?

Side note: Snapped golang would have been just fine with me, I wanted to check out mise later. I did it now with eval "$(~/.local/bin/mise activate bash)"; mise use -g go after already having installed the binary. So that problem is solved, snapd has one less responsibility to handle.

Observation and summary of the below:

The system was installed less than 3 months ago and this is the second critical issue. It's not like I install a lot of packages, do a lot of customization and do other crazy things.

Executing snap list takes now 5 seconds (2024-08-27T17:58:00+02:00 - 2024-08-27T17:58:05+02:00), this used to be almost instant. I can confirm that it takes no more than 2 seconds on another system.

snapd.socket seems to deactivate itself after executing the first call to snapd.
Error message: 
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get "http://localhost/v2/snaps": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
It takes 2 minutes before the error message appears (2024-08-27T17:58:13+02:00 -
2024-08-27T18:00:13+02:00)

This not only affects calls to snap list or go, but also Firefox.

Which does not really affect me as I rated snap and snapped Firefox as an unreliable piece of junk software and took the effort to configure and use Firefox from Flathub after the first problems I encountered with snapped Firefox years ago. Firefox from Flathub runs perfectly fine by the way.
This issue seems to creep up time and time again. Time and time again, from release the release I really want to give snap a chance, and it always breaks! Canonical you really need to fix your toxic broken software!


In the past users resorted to sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd and reinstalled snap. Since snap now holds the kernel and disk encryption keys, doing that without being 100% sure that the system remains bootable is a very bad idea. I don't worry about the content of my root partition and home directory, I can unlock the LUKS volume with a password since I have taken additional steps, in the likely worst case however the system will become unbootable and needs to be reinstalled.

In the end I was able to do sudo snap remove go while running while true; do sleep 10; [[ $(systemctl is-active snapd.socket) == inactive ]] && sudo systemctl start snapd.socket; done in another terminal. So snapd shows some signs of life, but it's beyond what average users will tolerate.

Someone suggested to check with systemctl status snapd.apparmor. It's enabled and running, the socket however still disables itself unless I use the while loop.


bt@za31:~$  snap list
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get "http://localhost/v2/snaps": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused

bt@za31:~$  sudo systemctl status snapd.socket
○ snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2024-08-27 17:49:43 CEST; 3min 52s ago
   Duration: 34.415s
   Triggers: ● snapd.service
     Listen: /run/snapd.socket (Stream)
             /run/snapd-snap.socket (Stream)
        CPU: 718us

Aug 27 17:49:08 za31 systemd[1]: Starting snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon...
Aug 27 17:49:08 za31 systemd[1]: Listening on snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Aug 27 17:49:43 za31 systemd[1]: snapd.socket: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 17:49:43 za31 systemd[1]: Closed snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon.

bt@za31:~$  sudo systemctl start snapd.socket
bt@za31:~$  sudo systemctl status snapd.socket
● snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (listening) since Tue 2024-08-27 17:53:49 CEST; 9s ago
   Triggers: ● snapd.service
     Listen: /run/snapd.socket (Stream)
             /run/snapd-snap.socket (Stream)
      Tasks: 0 (limit: 231600)
     Memory: 0B (peak: 0B)
        CPU: 756us
     CGroup: /system.slice/snapd.socket

Aug 27 17:53:49 za31 systemd[1]: Starting snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon...
Aug 27 17:53:49 za31 systemd[1]: Listening on snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon.

bt@za31:~$  date -Isec; snap list; date -Isec
2024-08-27T17:58:00+02:00
Name                       Version          Rev    Tracking              Publisher   Notes
bare                       1.0              5      latest/stable         canonical✓  base
canonical-livepatch        10.8.3           282    latest/stable         canonical✓  -
core22                     20240731         1564   latest/stable         canonical✓  base
firefox                    129.0.2-1        4793   latest/stable/…       mozilla✓    -
firmware-updater           0+git.5007558    127    latest/stable/…       canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204              0+git.510a601    176    latest/stable/…       canonical✓  -
go                         1.23.0           10698  latest/stable         canonical✓  classic
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511  1535   latest/stable/…       canonical✓  -
pc                         23.10-1          161    classic-24.04/stable  canonical✓  gadget,disabled
pc-kernel                  6.8.0-40.40      1938   24/stable             canonical✓  kernel
snap-store                 0+git.e3dd562    1173   latest/stable/…       canonical✓  -
snapd                      2.63             21759  latest/stable         canonical✓  snapd
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9              178    latest/stable/…       canonical✓  -
2024-08-27T17:58:05+02:00

bt@za31:~$  date -Isec; snap list; date -Isec
2024-08-27T17:58:13+02:00
error: cannot list snaps: cannot communicate with server: Get "http://localhost/v2/snaps": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: connection refused
2024-08-27T18:00:13+02:00

bt@za31:~$  sudo systemctl status snapd.socket
○ snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2024-08-27 17:57:49 CEST; 2min 38s ago
   Duration: 3min 59.843s
   Triggers: ● snapd.service
     Listen: /run/snapd.socket (Stream)
             /run/snapd-snap.socket (Stream)
        CPU: 756us

Aug 27 17:53:49 za31 systemd[1]: Starting snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon...
Aug 27 17:53:49 za31 systemd[1]: Listening on snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Aug 27 17:57:49 za31 systemd[1]: snapd.socket: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 27 17:57:49 za31 systemd[1]: Closed snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon.

bt@za31:~$  systemctl status snapd.apparmor
● snapd.apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.apparmor.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Tue 2024-08-27 17:22:52 CEST; 1h 27min ago
   Main PID: 1516 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 203ms

Aug 27 17:22:52 za31 systemd[1]: Starting snapd.apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
Aug 27 17:22:52 za31 snapd-apparmor[1516]: main.go:124: Loading profiles [/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.snapd.21465 /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap-confine.snapd.21>
Aug 27 17:22:52 za31 systemd[1]: Finished snapd.apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd.


Edit 2024-08-28
Today I took a laptop with the same Ubuntu TPM FDE installation which I can sacrifice and reinstall if needed without huge impact in my productivity.
Observations:

 sudo apt remove snapd & sudo apt install firefox gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd can be performed without much risk. the other system was still bootable. The problem with snapd was not solved on the affected machine though.

sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd fails with an error message that some hunspell files from Firefox cannot be deleted and therefore snapd cannot be removed completely removed. Result after reinstalling the packages: problem with snapd was not solved on the affected machine.

I tried removing the files myself with sudo rm -v ... and got the same error. I tried sudo touch /test.txt and sudo touch /var/snap/test.txt because I was not sure if I just did something bad to my filesystem. It seemed okay, the sacrifical laptop booted, I hope so does the workstation later.
Okay, you are using Ubuntu desktop you practically rely on snapd, so why would you ever want to remove it while it is working fine. I get it.
Note: We don't have such issues with Flatpak!


I asked Gemini, which basically gave me the same troubleshooting procedure and mentioning something like "Snapd socket is not created or corrupted". That's an interesting wording, from what I can seen and deduct the service that starts the socket and should keep it alive has a problem.


Test system:
bt@za28:~$  sudo apt remove snapd 
[sudo] password for bt: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 111 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 120027 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing gnome-software-plugin-snap (46.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
Stopping 'snapd.service', but its triggering units are still active:
snapd.socket
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.10-4ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...

bt@za28:~$  sudo apt install firefox gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 111 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.63.1+24.04 [28.0 MB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 firefox amd64 1:1snap1-0ubuntu5 [77.3 kB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 gnome-software-plugin-snap amd64 46.0-1ubuntu2 [31.1 kB]
Fetched 28.2 MB in 2s (18.5 MB/s)                     
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package snapd.
(Reading database ... 119923 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.63.1+24.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
Setting up snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Failed to restart snapd.mounts-pre.target: Operation refused, unit snapd.mounts-pre.target may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.mounts-pre.target' for details.
Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 148.
Selecting previously unselected package firefox.
(Reading database ... 120009 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the firefox snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the firefox snap
snap "firefox" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
=> Snap installation complete
Unpacking firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-software-plugin-snap.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-software-plugin-snap_46.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software-plugin-snap (46.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
Setting up gnome-software-plugin-snap (46.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.10-4ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...

# ---

bt@za28:~$  sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd 
[sudo] password for bt: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for bt: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox* gnome-software-plugin-snap* snapd*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
After this operation, 111 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 120027 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing gnome-software-plugin-snap (46.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
Stopping 'snapd.service', but its triggering units are still active:
snapd.socket
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.10-4ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
(Reading database ... 119922 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
Stopping snap-bare-5.mount
Stopping unit snap-bare-5.mount
Waiting until unit snap-bare-5.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-bare-5.mount is stopped.
Removing snap bare and revision 5
Removing snap-bare-5.mount
Stopping snap-core22-1439.mount
Stopping unit snap-core22-1439.mount
Waiting until unit snap-core22-1439.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-core22-1439.mount is stopped.
Removing snap core22 and revision 1439
Removing snap-core22-1439.mount
Stopping snap-core22-1564.mount
Stopping unit snap-core22-1564.mount
Waiting until unit snap-core22-1564.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-core22-1564.mount is stopped.
Removing snap core22 and revision 1564
Removing snap-core22-1564.mount
Stopping snap-firefox-4209.mount
Stopping unit snap-firefox-4209.mount
Waiting until unit snap-firefox-4209.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-firefox-4209.mount is stopped.
Removing snap firefox and revision 4209
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_DE.dic': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_DE.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_BE.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_LU.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.dic': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_LU.dic': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_BE.dic': Read-only file system
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
 installed snapd package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Purging configuration files for firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Affected system:
bt@za31:~$  sudo apt autoremove --purge snapd
[sudo] password for bt: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  firefox* gnome-software-plugin-snap* snapd*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 111 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 131140 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
Removing gnome-software-plugin-snap (46.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Removing snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
Stopping snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Stopping unit snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Waiting until unit snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service is stopped.
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.10-4ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
(Reading database ... 131035 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
Stopping snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Stopping unit snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Waiting until unit snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service is stopped [attempt 1]
snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service is stopped.
Removing snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Stopping snap-bare-5.mount
Stopping unit snap-bare-5.mount
Waiting until unit snap-bare-5.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-bare-5.mount is stopped.
Removing snap bare and revision 5
Removing snap-bare-5.mount
Stopping snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-278.mount
Stopping unit snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-278.mount
Waiting until unit snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-278.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-278.mount is stopped.
Removing snap canonical-livepatch and revision 278
Removing snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-278.mount
Stopping snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount
Stopping unit snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount
Waiting until unit snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount is stopped.
Removing snap canonical-livepatch and revision 282
Removing snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount
Stopping snap-core22-1439.mount
Stopping unit snap-core22-1439.mount
Waiting until unit snap-core22-1439.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-core22-1439.mount is stopped.
Removing snap core22 and revision 1439
Removing snap-core22-1439.mount
Stopping snap-core22-1564.mount
Stopping unit snap-core22-1564.mount
Waiting until unit snap-core22-1564.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-core22-1564.mount is stopped.
Removing snap core22 and revision 1564
Removing snap-core22-1564.mount
Stopping snap-firefox-4757.mount
Stopping unit snap-firefox-4757.mount
Waiting until unit snap-firefox-4757.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-firefox-4757.mount is stopped.
Removing snap firefox and revision 4757
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_LU.dic': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_BE.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_BE.dic': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.dic': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_LU.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_DE.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/de_DE.dic': Read-only file system
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
 installed snapd package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Purging configuration files for firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 snapd
[master XXXXXXX] committing changes in /etc made by "apt autoremove --purge snapd"
 Author: REDACTED
 25 files changed, 802 deletions(-)
 delete mode 120000 alternatives/gnome-www-browser
 delete mode 120000 alternatives/x-www-browser
 delete mode 100644 apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real
 delete mode 100644 apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
 delete mode 100644 profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
 delete mode 120000 systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-bare-5.mount
 delete mode 120000 "systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-278.mount"
 delete mode 120000 "systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-282.mount"
 delete mode 120000 systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-core22-1439.mount
 delete mode 120000 systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-core22-1564.mount
 delete mode 120000 systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
 delete mode 100644 systemd/system/snap-bare-5.mount
 delete mode 100644 "systemd/system/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-278.mount"
 delete mode 100644 "systemd/system/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-282.mount"
 delete mode 100644 systemd/system/snap-core22-1439.mount
 delete mode 100644 systemd/system/snap-core22-1564.mount
 delete mode 100644 systemd/system/snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
 delete mode 120000 systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-bare-5.mount
 delete mode 120000 "systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-278.mount"
 delete mode 120000 "systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-282.mount"
 delete mode 120000 systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-core22-1439.mount
 delete mode 120000 systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-core22-1564.mount
 delete mode 100644 udev/rules.d/70-snap.canonical-livepatch.rules
 delete mode 100644 xdg/autostart/snap-userd-autostart.desktop
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

bt@za31:~$  sudo apt install firefox gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  firefox gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 111 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates/main amd64 snapd amd64 2.63.1+24.04 [28.0 MB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/main amd64 firefox amd64 1:1snap1-0ubuntu5 [77.3 kB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 gnome-software-plugin-snap amd64 46.0-1ubuntu2 [31.1 kB]
Fetched 28.2 MB in 0s (103 MB/s)                       
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 131033 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../snapd_2.63.1+24.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
Setting up snapd (2.63.1+24.04) ...
snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.mounts-pre.target is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.mounts.target is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of snapd.apparmor.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of snapd.autoimport.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Warning: The unit file, source configuration file or drop-ins of snapd.core-fixup.service changed on disk. Run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload units.
Selecting previously unselected package firefox.
(Reading database ... 131123 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu5_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the firefox snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the firefox snap
snap "firefox" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'
=> Snap installation complete
Unpacking firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gnome-software-plugin-snap.
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-software-plugin-snap_46.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-software-plugin-snap (46.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up firefox (1:1snap1-0ubuntu5) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser (gnome-www-browser) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/firefox to provide /usr/bin/x-www-browser (x-www-browser) in auto mode
Setting up gnome-software-plugin-snap (46.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1.1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.12.0-4build2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.14.10-4ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.27-2build1) ...
[master XXXXXXX] committing changes in /etc made by "apt install firefox gnome-software-plugin-snap snapd"
 Author: REDACTED
 18 files changed, 765 insertions(+)
 create mode 120000 alternatives/gnome-www-browser
 create mode 120000 alternatives/x-www-browser
 create mode 100644 apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real
 create mode 100644 apt/apt.conf.d/20snapd.conf
 create mode 100644 profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh
 create mode 120000 systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-bare-5.mount
 create mode 120000 "systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-282.mount"
 create mode 120000 systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snap-core22-1564.mount
 create mode 100644 systemd/system/snap-bare-5.mount
 create mode 100644 "systemd/system/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-282.mount"
 create mode 100644 systemd/system/snap-core22-1564.mount
 create mode 100644 systemd/system/snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
 create mode 120000 systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-bare-5.mount
 create mode 120000 "systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-canonical\\x2dlivepatch-282.mount"
 create mode 120000 systemd/system/snapd.mounts.target.wants/snap-core22-1564.mount
 create mode 100644 udev/rules.d/70-snap.canonical-livepatch.rules
 create mode 100644 xdg/autostart/snap-userd-autostart.desktop
Scanning processes...                                                                                                                                                                      
Scanning candidates...                                                                                                                                                                     
Scanning processor microcode...                                                                                                                                                            
Scanning linux images...                                                                                                                                                                   

Failed to retrieve available kernel versions.

The processor microcode seems to be up-to-date.

Restarting services...

Service restarts being deferred:
 systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
 systemctl restart gdm.service
 systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
 systemctl restart unattended-upgrades.service

No containers need to be restarted.

User sessions running outdated binaries:
 bt @ session #3: gdm-session-wor[13310], gdm-wayland-ses[13383]
 bt @ user manager service: bwrap[15086,52275,320875,371059,371167,371540,372204], gnome-session-b[13511], gnome-shell[13552], gnome-terminal[15149], gvfsd[13501], ibus-daemon[13740],
  systemd[2709]

No VM guests are running outdated hypervisor (qemu) binaries on this host.


I think you're basically wasting your time by posting it here with all this detail, when you should be reporting it as a bug, where the devs can use the details for debugging

Edit 2024-09-28:
The file /var/lib/snapd/device/disk-mapping.json contains device name which might need to be updated after modifications which affect the numbering of devices. Changing nvme2 to nvme4, or whatever could be identified as the Ubuntu FDE disk in lsblk or Gnome Disks, followed by systemctl start snapd.socket should revive snapd. The socket restart might not even be necessary as snapd.failure.service
should soon attempt to resolve the issue, which can be checked with journalctl -e --unit snapd.failure.service. I did a sudo snap refresh pc-kernel; snap list and was able to reboot successfully. Affected users should check their machines this way before a reboot, otherwise they will boot into said mode where not network connection is available. I was able to recover from this situation, but it's no clear to me yet what besides changing the device name returned the system back to normal. Simply changing the device name was not sufficient during a few attempts.
Edit 2024-09-06:

As I have written, I attempted to reinstall the snapd package, which did not solve the issue. A few days and reboots (updates?) later I found that my system booted into some kind of restricted mode. Only one display was working at low resolution, network and many storage devices were missing. Without any knowledge how to troubleshoot a snapped pc-kernel installation under these circumstances a reinstall was inevitable. USB storage devices were not detected, so to create a backup of the last state the live media had to be used. On a positive note: ZFS works in the live media environment out of the box!
The error message from snap-failure about "No such device" has not appeared again or does not lead to a critical failure of snapd. I have no time to check further yet.


Thinking about the situation in this particular case, a temporary workaround would be one of these:

Reinstall Ubuntu and avoid changing any reconfiguration of the hardware that could change the order of storage devices when using TPM FDE installation. This is easy for laptop users, but for desktop and workstation users it kind of defeats the purpose of having a machine where you can swap and reconfigure parts.
Run a script like while true; do sleep 10; sudo systemctl start snapd.socket; done or while true; do sleep 10; [[ $(systemctl is-active snapd.socket) == inactive ]] && sudo systemctl start snapd.socket; done in the background. The latter requires sudoers configuration, the former feels a bit more clunky. Well, both are sub optimal.


For a long term solution Ubuntu should:

Correct the logic that apparently hard codes the boot device leading to an errror mesasge like this:
Aug 28 15:52:25 za31 snap-failure[650745]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: Running task 723 on Doing: Update assets from gadget "pc" (184)
Aug 28 15:52:25 za31 snap-failure[650745]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: cannot locate disk for volume pc with method device path because err:
Aug 28 15:52:25 za31 snap-failure[650745]: -----
Aug 28 15:52:25 za31 snap-failure[650745]: stderr:
Aug 28 15:52:25 za31 snap-failure[650745]: Unknown device "/sys/devices/pci0000:20/0000:20:01.2/0000:2d:00.0/nvme/nvme2/nvme2n1": No such device
Aug 28 15:52:25 za31 snap-failure[650745]: -----
Aug 28 15:52:25 za31 snap-failure[650745]: logger.go:93: DEBUG: OnDiskStructureFromPartition: p.FilesystemType "", p.FilesystemLabel ""


Review the configuration of snapd and provide clear troubleshooting instructions for such cases.


